# Writing a simple event dispatcher in c++ -- how do I avoid self-referencing and recursion problems?

Tags: c++, events, event-handling

I am attempting to write a simple event dispatcher in C++. I am very new to this particular arena so please forgive my ignorance.

For the dispatch process, I have the following interface:

```
class listener
{
    public:
       virtual void triggerEvent(int id)=0;
};
```

Then to incorporate it, I simply implement it:

```
class A : public listener
{
    public:
           A();
           void triggerEvent(int event);
           .
           .
           .
           B* b;
};
```

In a class which has a listener pointer called listener_ that points to an A object, an event in A can be triggered as shown,

```
 void B::method()
 {
       .
       .
       .
       listener_->triggerEvent(DO_SOMETHING); // calling point
 }
```

But now the problem is, is that A also has a pointer to a B object such that when A's triggerEvent implementation is called, B::method() is called right back again, i.e.:

```
 void A::triggerEvent(int id)
 {
      if(id==DO_SOMETHING)b->method();
 }
```

This then causes problems of recursion.

Ideally, I want the 'calling point' in B::method() to be immediately freed from the stack. How do I do this so that the above recursion problems are prevented? What is incorrect about my event dispatcher design? How do I fix it?

EDIT: Shown above is a very extreme example. In a real situation, A might actually be some `control thread'. B might then be a separate algorithm that needs to indicate to the control thread when its finished so that A can proceed with further operations. B::method might also be a thread.

Thanks and best wishes,

Ben.

Comment: Why is a class that *raises* events called `listener`? Does `A` always need a pointer to `B::method` and if so, why? Finally, why would an event handler raise the event that it's already subscribed to?

Comment: Thanks Jon. I chose to call it listener because it 'listens' to other parts of the program and acts accordingly when triggered by particular events. As somebody already pointed out, I've implemented the observer pattern. Also see edit in question.

Answer (score 0):

You're implementing the **observer pattern**.

> What is incorrect about my event dispatcher design?

The fact that you call the method that triggers the events inside an event handler. You fix it by not calling the method.

Comment: Luchian, thanks for your answer. But what if tiggerEvent is required to call another method in A which then finally calls B::method? Post also edited at bottom.

Comment: @BenJ regardless of how many calls you have, you're still saying you want your even handler to trigger the event handler, right?

Comment: You make it sound like its a bad thing ;-) In all seriousness, a part of the program in B is required to indicate to A when it has finished. A then carries out a bunch of unrelated operations before telling B to do it all over again. -- Sounds like a loop. Scratching my head now...Its done this way because B is actually within its own thread.

Comment: @BenJ take a look at the state pattern. Maybe you need a message passed to the function, telling it whether it needs to notify listeners, or at least which listeners to notify (or not).

Comment: Thanks Luchian, will have a look. Cheers.